# CollectionView GridItemsLayout Change BackgroundColor of nested Item (Button)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, selecteditem, xamarin.forms.collectionview

I have a problem concerning a `CollectionView` with a `GridItemsLayout`. In my application, I have a `StackLayout` with a horizontal `CollectionView(GridItemsLayout)`, which contains a Button bound to a certain category.

Whenever a button is clicked/tapped, it filters the `ListView` (of type Surgery) below based on the category. All of that is working fine, however, I would like to highlight the Category/Button by changing it `BackgroundColor` to see which category is currently used for filtering.

```
<CollectionView HeightRequest="70"
                    x:Name="categoryCollection"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                    Margin="20,0,20,0"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Span="1" HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="0,5,0,5">
                    <Button x:Name="categoryButton" Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.FilterCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=SurgeryListView}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            CornerRadius="15"
                            FontFamily="OpenSans" Margin="0,5,10,5"
                            Opacity="0.6" FontSize="16" TextTransform="None">
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

 <ListView x:Name="listView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Surgeries}"
              RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadSurgeriesCommand}"
              IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              RowHeight="70"
              BackgroundColor="{StaticResource darkThemeBackground}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource surgeryDataTemplateSelector}">

        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
                EventName="ItemTapped"
                Command="{Binding SurgerySelectedCommand}"
                EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ItemTappedConverter}">
            </behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior>
        </ListView.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
```

I tried to use `VisualStates` but that was not working, because tapping the button does not actually change the `SelectedItem` (one would need to click the surrounding/parent grid element for that). Moreover, the altered `VisualState` was only applied to the Grid's `BackgroundColor`, not to that of the actual button.

Question: How can I highlight the current Category/Button by changing its Background Color?

Comment: it filters the ListView or the CollectionView?

Comment: It filters a ListView below (just added the code for clarification) The filtering functionality itself is working fine! I just can't highlight the selected button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the selection is working good, remains only the ui/xaml part, if you look at the documentation about [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color), you can add the following style:

```
<CollectionView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                        <VisualStateGroupList>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateGroupList>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
</CollectionView.Resources>
```